# Search is not working in Ask Ubuntu Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

I searched "flag" in Ask Ubuntu help center and I got this error:

> ### Oops! Something Bad Happened!
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. **This is our fault.**
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.askubuntu.com.

[image: Screenshot of error shown in Help Center]

Since it's mentioned

> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, https://meta.askubuntu.com.

I have posted this.

Comment: Thanks, have pinged our SRE team to dig into the cause

Comment: @DeanWard Is the issue fixed now? Is it [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: yup, fixed a while ago now, marking as [tag:status-completed]